# Pass config/options from FormEvent to the buildView method

Tags: forms, symfony

I am working with Symfony 2.7. Is it somehow possible to pass information form a `FormEvent` handler back to the `buildView` method?

I use `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` to check the data and would like add some options/information to the formType in `buildView` depending on the result:

```
class MyEntitiesType extends AbstractType {
    ...
    public function getParent() {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'my_entities_type';
    }  

    private $globalVar = false;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
            $data = $event->getData();

            // $data is an array of myEntity. Check in some
            // 'special' myEntity instances are included. Remove
            // these instances from the data/selection and remember
            // this to update the view in buildView

            if (someSpecialEntitiesUsed($data)) {
                $data = removeSpecialEntities($data); 

                // Will work but will deliver false results, since
                // there is only one instance for all MyEntitiesTypes
                // within the form
                $this->globalVar = true;

                // Will not work, since array is not passed by reference
                // ==> global version of $options is not updated
                // $options['specialDataUsed'] = true;

                // Would be a good solution but so such methode...
                $builder->setSomeOptions(...)

                // EntityType will only accept managed objects as
                // data. I do not want to add data but only config information
                $data[] = $someSpecialDataObject; 

                $event->setData($data);
            }
        }
        ...
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) { 
        $data = $view->vars['data'];

        // This will return false, since the special entities
        // have already been filtered out in buildForm
        someSpecialEntitiesUsed($data) 

        // How to get the information, that entities have been
        // filtered out?
        $entitiesFiltered = ...;

        if (entitiesFiltered) {
            $view->vars['show_hint'] = true;
            ...
        }
    } 
}
```

I have already tried different options to pass the information about filtered entities from `buildForm` to `buildView` (see source above) but none of them worked.

**Is that possible somehow?**

Of course I perform the check `someSpecialEntitiesUsed($data)` not with in my FormType implementation, but within the Form instead:

```
class MyForm extends AbstractType {
    ...

    public function getName() {
        return 'my_form';
    }  

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $entities = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $used = someSpecialEntitiesUsed($data)

            $form
                ->add('entities', 'my_entities_type', array(
                    ...
                    'specialDataUsed' => used,
                    ...,
                ));
            });
        }
    }
```

However in this solution I have to update **all** forms that use `my_entities_type` which are quite a lot. Additionally this logic belongs to `my_entities_type` and not to the forms that are using this type. So finding a solution for `my_entities_type` would be much cleaner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no exact answer to this question, but I'll try to follow some logic of Form component.

First of all I want to notice that the main work for event listeners was always to modify form, not the data. And you trying to brake this logic removing some entities.

Another thing is that form configuration (`FormConfig`) is designed in a way that says loudly "DON'T TRY TO MODIFY ME". So we'll better don't.

And the third thing is that to modify data that bound to the form there are DataTransformers.

Following this logic and your goal I can suggest creating another form that will be called like `my_entities_type_filtered` and add `DataTransformer` which will remove unnecessary data to it. And so you can add this internal `my_entities_type_filtered` in your `my_entities_type` with your flag that can be used then at `buildView`.

```
<?php
//...
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {     
    $data = $event->getData();
    $specialEntitiesUsed = someSpecialEntitiesUsed($data);
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $form->add('someinnerfieldname', MyEntitiesType::class, [
        'property_path' => $form->getPropertyPath(), // if this won't work as expected you should add data transformer to this form also.
        'special' => $specialEntitiesUsed 
    ]);
```